# using facebook notifications in my own Facebook application

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, notifications

I am trying to devolop my own Facebook application using `Codeigniter`, am asking about how i can implement Facebook notifications when a user adds or someone comments in his post, is it possible to implement this using Facebook notifications rather than email notifications ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

Comment: what about the notification which is sent to the users, can it be just like Facebook applications ?

Comment: Where & how it appears is described on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send notifications to users via the API. Notifications are generated automatically when someone takes an action on Facebook, e.g. comments on a status, likes a status, application requests.

The only way you can notify a user is to use Requests - either from the user or from the app. Both are [detailed here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/). You can use "user to user" requests or "app to user" requests.